# The loss and accuracy of val data in fitting process is not equal with the evaluate process

Tags: machine-learning, keras

The loss and accuracy of val data in fitting process are not equal with the evaluate process.
And I used image_generator.
The code is in attachement. incep_v3.py is fitting code,model_app.py is evaluate code.

[E:\Jason\incep_v3.py](https://stackoverflow.com)

[E:\Jason\model_app.py](https://stackoverflow.com)

The fitting log:

```
Epoch 00001: saving model to ./training2/cp-01.ckpt
Epoch 2/30
150/150 [==============================] - 368s 2s/step - loss: 0.0675 - accuracy: 0.9787 - val_loss: 0.1083 - val_accuracy: 0.9375

Epoch 00002: saving model to ./training2/cp-02.ckpt
Epoch 3/30
150/150 [==============================] - 382s 3s/step - loss: 0.0506 - accuracy: 0.9808 - val_loss: 0.0429 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00003: saving model to ./training2/cp-03.ckpt
Epoch 4/30
150/150 [==============================] - 335s 2s/step - loss: 0.0433 - accuracy: 0.9833 - val_loss: 0.1925 - val_accuracy: 0.8750

Epoch 00004: saving model to ./training2/cp-04.ckpt
Epoch 5/30
150/150 [==============================] - 337s 2s/step - loss: 0.0573 - accuracy: 0.9792 - val_loss: 0.2156 - val_accuracy: 0.9375

Epoch 00005: saving model to ./training2/cp-05.ckpt
Epoch 6/30
150/150 [==============================] - 336s 2s/step - loss: 0.0383 - accuracy: 0.9867 - val_loss: 0.0069 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
```

I load the cp-05.ckpt to evaluate, the evaluating log:
0.20122399926185608 0.9712499976158142

Comment: My code file seems not upload.How to upload the code file?

Comment: To attach file: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47689/how-can-i-attach-a-file-to-a-post